# Extract the last element of a list for a split string

Tags: hive, impala

I'm trying to take a regular expression and split it by a pre-determined character, and then extract the final value of the returned list.

For example, my string may take the form:

```
name
WAYNE.ROONEY.226
ROSS.BARKLEY.HELLO.113
ADAM.A122
```

Pythonically, what I'm trying to do is:

```
for x in list:
  my_val = x.split('.')[-1] #Return the last element of the list when split on .
```

e.g. desired output:

```
name                         value
WAYNE.ROONEY.226             226
ROSS.BARKLEY.HELLO.113       113
ADAM.A122                    A122
```

Can anyone provide me any pointers in either Hive or Impala please?

If I can create this as a view, ideally, that would be perfect, but am also happy with generating actual output with it and then re-uploading to a table

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hive:

```
select regexp_extract(NAME, '\\.([^\\.]+)$', 1) as VALUE
from WHATEVER
```

And pleeeease *[edit]* learn the power of regular expressions...

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get back to the office. I did read the documentation, and came across `split`, but couldnt get it working to extract the last element of the array it returned. I think your answer also doesnt work - you're always extracting the first index, the challenge is in extracting the *last* element, which is dynamic and unknown.

Comment: The regular expression (in Java dialect) translates as "get all non-dot characters placed between a dot and end-of-string", so there can be only 1 match by definition... with a `sed`command-line, the equivalent of the whole "regexp_extract" stuff would be `s/^.*\.\([^\.][^\.]*\)$/\1/` in old-style syntax.

Comment: When it comes to manipulating strings, quite often you can replace tens of lines of procedural code with a one-liner using a couple of regular expression. OK, it's a bit cryptic, but it works. And `sed` rocks when all you want to do is clean-up an input file.

Comment: Ah ha. Thank you Samson. Regex was always a weakness for me, to be honest. Thank you kindly, I'll give it a whirl and see if it works, will report back.